# Alert id of contents fetched from php while loop using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery and ajax. I have a PHP while loop which display contents from database. What I need is simply alert the "content_id" on click of each contents.

My script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
  $(".show_id").click(function() {


  var test = $(".contentid").val();
  alert(test);
  });
</script>
```

PHP Code

```
//code to fetch contents from database

foreach($stmt as $row)
{
   echo $row['content'];
?>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" class="contentid"  value="<?php echo $row['content_id']; ?>">
    <div class="show_id" ></div>
  </form>
 <?php
}
  ?>
```

**It Alerts the id for each content, But only the first id always .**

How to alert id for each contents respectively ?.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: what you get on _console.log($(".contentid"));_ ? and why create new form tag in foreach ?

Comment: @DelightedD0D: it alerts blank now

Comment: `var test = $(".contentid input[type=\"hidden\"]").val();` try this

Comment: @devpro why would that produce different results?

Comment: @DelightedD0D: i didnt say, its a solution

Comment: @DelightedD0D: it shows "undefined". whats wrong with these? any other method will be appreciated, that is not using form.. i need only a button to get the value

Comment: @newbie did you try the solution I posted below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
 $(function() {
   $(".show_id").click(function() {
     var cur = $(".show_id").index($(this)); // get the index of the clicked button within the collection
     var test = $(".contentid").eq(cur).val(); // find the input with the contentid class at the same index and get its value
     alert(test);
   });
 });
```

Note that this assumes that the two classes are always paired together like you show and not used elsewhere in your html, which seems a reasonable assumption here

Comment: @newbie Id get rid of all those forms too if you dont need them, doesnt seem that you do, Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".show_id").click(function() {
            var test = $(this).prev(".contentid").val();
            alert(test);
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect!...This also nice one...you're the Real Boss !!

Comment: @jersten: Didnt get you